# Ambigiuous method call between extension methods

Tags: c#, .net

I have been download DynamicLinq library via nuget package. I used it like below

```
db.ReservationSet.Where("blbalbabla",1,2)
```

But i get below exception.

> Error 38  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   string, params object[])' and
>   'System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Where(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   string, params
>   object[])'    F:\Projects\IEKeysNew\IEKEYS\Controllers\ReportController.cs    145 22  IEKEYS

Here is sign of both methods.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string predicate, params object[] values);
public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string predicate, params object[] values);
```

I could not find something to get rid of this compile time exception.

Comment: It0s giving you an ambigous exception between the same method (it's not considering the Generic Where in the exception). Sometimes that happens to me, try to clean solution, and build again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately another third party .dll library contains the same dynamic linq library internaly. Trirand's jQGrid library contains dynamic linq library and that is the reason for the conflict when I import System.Linq.Dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following using from your code :

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: No it does not affect result as expected already this conflict cause from same library methods.

Comment: I don't think this is not the problem. `Enumerable.Where` has another type signature, and the error message does not even mention `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Comment: @Freshblood: try to rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

What type does `db.ReservationSet` has?

If it's collection of instances of your `MyClass` then try to write `db.ReservationSet.Where<MyClass>("blbalbabla",1,2)`.

If it is assignable to `IQueryable` then try to write:
`((IQueryable )db.ReservationSet).Where("blbalbabla",1,2)`

Comment: I have been already tried but check my answer i found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the prettiest way. But I do not have another idea.

Split your class to 2 cs files and create partial classes. So u delete the using `System.Linq` from one of the documents.
Try it maybe it works.